# How do I put an enter in a <li>?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: example]

So I'm talking about the enter after ''Opleidingen'' in ''AI Opleidingen & verenigingen''

What I have:

```
                <ul class="firstNavBar">
                <li><a href="#">Wat is AI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">De Connectie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AI Opleidingen 
                    & verenigingen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AI Masters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
```

I'm a complete noob at HTML and CSS so sorry if I'm a bit vague.

Comment: Are your list items `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about a line break.  You can do with this with a  `<br>` tag.

Comment: Upvoting this because you didn't use the self-closing slash, which is no longer necessary.

Comment: show your CSS too. Looks like CSS affects the width of the list.

Comment: @Emmy replace inline with inline-block

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks. I figured it out! Now to make it align :-)

Comment: Okay so now it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/Zvh3V36.png How do I make it look like my example?

Comment: @Emmy you can try my answe also ;) i provide a full code with CSS that will make it look like you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269184/8620333 ... or simply add `vertical-align:top` to li

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add [`<br>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) to create a new line / line break in HTML:

```html
<ul class="firstNavBar">
  <li><a href="#">Wat is AI</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">De Connectie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AI Opleidingen<br>
      & verenigingen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AI Masters</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another (automatic) solution using CSS can be the following using `max-width`:

```css
ul li {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstNavBar">
  <li><a href="#">Wat is AI</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">De Connectie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AI Opleidingen & verenigingen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AI Masters</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Solution using your CSS:**

```css
.firstnav {
  position:absolute;
  top:75%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  margin-top:-300px;
}
.firstnav li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 25px;
  vertical-align:top;
} 
.firstnav a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;  
  font-size:25px; 
  max-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstnav">
  <li><a href="#">Wat is AI</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">De Connectie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AI Opleidingen<br> & verenigingen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AI Masters</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the `/` for br is not needed we can omit it

Comment: @TemaniAfif It’s a matter of taste. I’ll include the `/` in my code because I feel it improves readability.

Comment: @Xufox it should not be a matter of taste :) in HTML5 you don't have to specify it so you should get used to it. Maybe one day it won't work.

Comment: @Xufox I don't because it's ugly and unnecessary. Not a single element needs it.